# Query data based on time interval/frequency

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to have a calendar display a series of activities based on their type, time and frequency for an easier visualization of data.

So far, I have managed to create a formula that correctly fetches the data that I have on a repository and displays it on the calendar. However, I'm not sure how I can have it account for entries that have a frequency (happening every x days).

For an easier understanding here are screenshots of both the table and the schedule
[image: table]

[image: schedule]

And here's the current formula I'm using to display the event/activity title in each day/hour at C12 for example:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(Repository!$K:$K, 
        MATCH(
            C$10, 
            IF(
                (Repository!$G:$G=$G$8)*
                (Repository!$H:$H=$K$8)*
                (Repository!$N:$N>=$B12)*
                (Repository!$N:$N<$B12+TIME(2,0,0)),
               Repository!$D:$D),
            0)
         ),
      "")
```

What I'm currently missing on the formula is a way to correctly account for the start/end date as well as frequency and understand if each day falls under the specified criteria. In case the frequency is 0 then I'd like to have it discard the end date at all (in case for some reason I end up forgetting to set the end date).

I have tried to work with the formula provided to account for the frequency but nothing that I tried seemed to work.

### **Minimal example requested by @GabrielCarballo**

Entry on the table with a 2 days frequency:
[image: entry table]

Expected result on the schedule:
[image: entry schedule]

So basically, the formula on each cell should check for the start date, end date and frequency of the activity and identify if the specific date on the schedule falls under the specified timeframe.

In this minimal example, the activity starts on the 7th December and repeats every 2 days until the 14th of December.

Comment: Could you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo I have included a minimal example at the bottom of the post as requested. Please let me know if it's clear

Comment: Usually, users means to share actually a spreadsheet with some dummy data that reflects your situation, why? because they're not really eager to go and type again all your inputs to replicate your situation, then solve your problem then post the solution. That's why is always better to share a spreadsheet directly.

Answer (score 0):

use in C6:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TEXT(C4:P4+B6:B14, "e-m-d-h-m")&G$2&K$2, SPLIT(FLATTEN(MAP(
 Repository!D$4:D, Repository!O$4:O, Repository!P$4:P, Repository!N$4:N, 
 Repository!G$4:G, Repository!H$4:H, Repository!K$4:K, LAMBDA(d, o, p, n, g, h, k, 
 IF(DAYS(o, d)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(o, d)), 0, p), TEXT(d+SEQUENCE(1, 
 MAX(DAYS(o, d)), 0, p)+IF(ISODD(HOUR(n)), (HOUR(n)*"1:00")-"1:00", HOUR(n)*"1:00"), 
 "e-m-d-h-m")&g&h&"×"&k, )))), "×"), 2, )))
```